# Mysql search only "7" in text not "17"

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have huge database that contain long string I just to find row that has "7" not "17" or any 7 combination ..

I used like "%7%" but it get 17 also !

all my rows have other string not just a single number . and I have to use like .

Comment: Why do you have to use `LIKE`?

Comment: @t.niese give me other option please

Comment: You should be reading [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You said that you have to use `LIKE`. And my question is why you have that limitation. So how should I be able to to tell you another option if you can’t tell me why you have that limitation?

Comment: @t.niese no limitaion !

Comment: See if `FIND_IN_SET()` does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `RLIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col RLIKE '(^|[^0-9])7([^0-9]|$)'
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbc8310e2c8b64c9ea5042e5c670d502)**

Comment: Maybe not the case, but the dot `.` should also be excluded just like the digits, so to avoid decimals like `0.7` and `7.1`.

Comment: @forpas Well, then the `-` and `e` for scientific notation should be excluded as well :)

Comment: @forpas it's work on only string contain 7 , not match  single 7 string  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=44d0ea018e6d248c1d2fa2bd27ee4e55

Comment: @devmoore Extended to match single 7